# Using Animator IK how can I detect when the player hand finished move forward?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class IKControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InteractableItem[] lookObj = null;
    public GameObject objToThrow;
    public Text text;
    public float weightDamping = 1.5f;
    public float maxDistance = 10f;
    public bool RightHandToTarget = true;
    public float throwSpeed;
    public bool handFinishedMove = false;

    private List<InteractableItem> allDetectedItems;
    private Animator animator;
    private InteractableItem lastPrimaryTarget;
    private float lerpEndDistance = 0.1f;
    private float finalLookWeight = 0;
    private bool transitionToNextTarget = false;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        allDetectedItems = new List<InteractableItem>();
    }

    // Callback for calculating IK
    void OnAnimatorIK()
    {
        if (lookObj != null)
        {
            InteractableItem primaryTarget = null;
            float closestLookWeight = 0;

            // Here we find the target which is closest (by angle) to the players view line
            allDetectedItems.Clear();
            foreach (InteractableItem target in lookObj)
            {
                Vector3 lookAt = target.transform.position - transform.position;
                lookAt.y = 0f;

                // Filter out all objects that are too far away
                //if (lookAt.magnitude > maxDistance) continue;
                if (lookAt.magnitude > target.distance) continue;

                float dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(new Vector3(transform.forward.x, 0f, transform.forward.z).normalized, lookAt.normalized);
                float lookWeight = Mathf.Clamp(dotProduct, 0f, 1f);
                if (lookWeight > 0.1f && lookWeight > closestLookWeight)
                {
                    closestLookWeight = lookWeight;
                    primaryTarget = target;
                    allDetectedItems.Add(target);
                }
            }

            if (primaryTarget != null)
            {
                if ((lastPrimaryTarget != null) && (lastPrimaryTarget != primaryTarget) && (finalLookWeight > 0f))
                {
                    // Here we start a new transition because the player looks already to a target but
                    // we have found another target the player should look at
                    transitionToNextTarget = true;
                }
            }

            // The player is in a neutral look position but has found a new target
            if ((primaryTarget != null) && !transitionToNextTarget)
            {
                if(primaryTarget.actionwithoutthrow == true)
                {
                    RightHandToTarget = true;
                }

                lastPrimaryTarget = primaryTarget;
                //finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, closestLookWeight, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, 1f, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                float bodyWeight = finalLookWeight * .75f;
                animator.SetLookAtWeight(finalLookWeight, bodyWeight, 1f);
                animator.SetLookAtPosition(primaryTarget.transform.position);

                if (RightHandToTarget && primaryTarget.interactableMode == InteractableItem.InteractableMode.Action
                    || RightHandToTarget && primaryTarget.interactableMode == InteractableItem.InteractableMode.ActionWithoutThrow)
                {
                    Vector3 relativePos = primaryTarget.transform.position - transform.position;
                    Quaternion rotationtoTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
                    animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKRotation(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, rotationtoTarget);
                    animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight * 1f * closestLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, primaryTarget.transform.position);

                    // -> new code block
                    if (finalLookWeight > 0.95f) // here you can play with a value between 0.95f -> 1.0f
                    {
                        handFinishedMove = true;

                        if(primaryTarget.action == true && primaryTarget.interactableMode == InteractableItem.InteractableMode.Action)
                        // call your funtion to shoot something here
                        StartCoroutine(ThrowObject(objToThrow.transform, primaryTarget.transform.position, 30f));
                    }
                }
            }

            // Let the player smoothly look away from the last target to the neutral look position
            if ((primaryTarget == null && lastPrimaryTarget != null) || transitionToNextTarget)
            {
                finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, 0f, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                float bodyWeight = finalLookWeight * .75f;
                animator.SetLookAtWeight(finalLookWeight, bodyWeight, 1f);
                animator.SetLookAtPosition(lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position);

                if (RightHandToTarget)
                {
                    Vector3 relativePos = lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position - transform.position;
                    Quaternion rotationtoTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
                    animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKRotation(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, rotationtoTarget);
                    animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight * 0.5f * closestLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position);
                }

                if (finalLookWeight < lerpEndDistance)
                {
                    transitionToNextTarget = false;
                    finalLookWeight = 0f;
                    lastPrimaryTarget = null;
                }
            }

            // Show primary object found by the player
            if (primaryTarget != null)
            {
                text.text = primaryTarget.description;
            }
            else
            {
                text.text = "";
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ThrowObject(Transform objectToMove, Vector3 toPosition, float duration)
    {
        float counter = 0;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            Vector3 currentPos = objectToMove.position;

            float time = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, toPosition) / (duration - counter) * Time.deltaTime;

            objectToMove.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPos, toPosition, time);

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I added a new flag name handFinishedMove and tried to use it in line 99 set it to true :

```
if (RightHandToTarget && primaryTarget.interactableMode == InteractableItem.InteractableMode.Action
                    || RightHandToTarget && primaryTarget.interactableMode == InteractableItem.InteractableMode.ActionWithoutThrow)
                {
                    Vector3 relativePos = primaryTarget.transform.position - transform.position;
                    Quaternion rotationtoTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
                    animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKRotation(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, rotationtoTarget);
                    animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight * 1f * closestLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, primaryTarget.transform.position);

                    // -> new code block
                    if (finalLookWeight > 0.95f) // here you can play with a value between 0.95f -> 1.0f
                    {
                        handFinishedMove = true;

                        if(primaryTarget.action == true && primaryTarget.interactableMode == InteractableItem.InteractableMode.Action)
                        // call your funtion to shoot something here
                        StartCoroutine(ThrowObject(objToThrow.transform, primaryTarget.transform.position, 30f));
                    }
                }
```

Then in another script : but handFinishedMove is never true.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class UnlockCrate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject carte;
    public Animation anim;
    public IKControl ikControl;

    private bool playAnimOnce = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(carte.transform.position, transform.position);

        if (distance < 1.5f)
        {
            if (!playAnimOnce)
            {
                if(ikControl.handFinishedMove == true)
                {
                    anim.Play("Crate_Open");
                }

                playAnimOnce = true;
            }
        }
        else if (playAnimOnce)
        {
            anim.Play("Crate_Close");
            playAnimOnce = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to check if the final  is greater then 0.9f

```
if(finalLookWeight > 0.9f)
                    {
                        handFinishedMove = true;
                    }
```

The hand weight is changing between 0 and 1 but it's never reaching to 1 it will get to 0.9 and then the value will move up slowly 0.912345 and so on. So in this case it's enough to check if the finalWeight is greater then 0.9f but I'm not sure if this is the cleanest solution but since it's working I'll mark it as solution.

The hand raise up pointing the target and 0.9f is accurate enough I guess.